# How can I get my old villager back (I want them to remember me)? - Animal Crossing New Leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I want to get Camofrog back and I've heard about the 16 villager cycle. However I don't know where he moved to... so my initial question is... can I get him back if he randomly appears in my campsite? After cycling out 16 villagers, is there a chance he could appear in my campsite again, and if so, will he remember me?

Answer (score 1):

He/she could reappear in your campsite but will NOT remember you at all. This happened to me and the resident did not remember me